# Translating Matlab function to R

Tags: r, matlab

I am having a lot of trouble translating a piece of matlab-code to R. I am probably missing something conceptually. My matlab in its whole is:

```
nobs = 2000;

x = cumsum([0;randn(nobs,1)/sqrt(nobs)]);
k = 1;
n = size(x,1);

dx = zeros(n-k,1);

% to calculate dx - This is the part I am having trouble with
for i = k : n - 1
    sumx = 0;

for j = 0 : k
    sumx = sumx + (-1)^j*nchoosek(k,j)*x(i-j+1);
end   

dx(i-k+1) = sumx;
end
```

I have tried to make a function, that works. But this function only does the following part of the matlab code:

```
for j = 0 : k
    sumx = sumx + (-1)^j*nchoosek(k,j)*x(i-j+1);
end
```

So far, i've done this in R, which corresponds to the first part of the trouble code:

```
function (n,i,k){
  sumx <- 0
  for (j in 0:k){
    term <- ((-1)^j)*choose(k,j)*xsub((i-j)/n)
    sumx <- sumx + term 
  }
  return(sumx)
}
```

Now this works, but I can't get it to sum across i?

```
for (k in 1:2){
   for (i in k:10){
    ?????????????????????
   }
}
```

Comment: Please describe in words what it is you're trying to do (instead of just posting the matlab code). It will also be helpful to show the R code you've implemented so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: You're "having trouble getting it to sum over i, and I can't get it to return a vector." What _is_ it returning, and what exactly is the "trouble?"

Comment: Right, thanks for the feedback. I've added my R-code and tried to make it more clear what I am having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have matlab here. So compare the results with a known sequence, like `rse=c(1:5)/100`

```
nobs = 2000;
rse=rnorm(nobs)
#rse=c(1:5)/100
x = cumsum(c(0,rse/sqrt((length(rse))));
k = 1;
n = length(x);
dx = rep(0,n-k);
for (i in k:(n - 1)){
  sumx = 0;
  for (j in 0:k)
    sumx = sumx + (-1)^j*choose(k,j)*x[i-j+1];
  dx[i-k+1] = sumx;
}
plot(dx~x[-(1:k)],col=3)
```

> ```
> > cbind(dx,x=x[-(1:k)],rse)
>               dx           x  rse
> [1,] 0.004472136 0.004472136 0.01
> [2,] 0.008944272 0.013416408 0.02
> [3,] 0.013416408 0.026832816 0.03
> [4,] 0.017888544 0.044721360 0.04
> [5,] 0.022360680 0.067082039 0.05
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it using vectorisation. Often in R if you're using a for loop there's a better way.

```
nobs <- 2000
x <- cumsum(c(0, rnorm(nobs)/sqrt(nobs)))
k <- 1
n <- length(x)
dx <- numeric(n - k)
is <- k:(n - 1)
dx[is - k + 1] <- sapply(is, function(i) sum((-1) ^ j * choose(k, j) * x[i - j + 1]))
```

But it should be noted that since `k = 1` and `j = c(0,1)` the choose statement just evaluates to `c(1, 1)`.

So the whole thing could be done as:

```
nobs <- 2000
x <- cumsum(c(0, rnorm(nobs)/sqrt(nobs)))
dx <- x[-1] - x[-(nobs + 1)]
```